# How to determine the pre-image point for this transformed function?

Tags: functions

A function $f(x)$ is transformed to $2f(-7x-4)+10$.
Let $(6,5)$ be a point on the transformed graph.
What is $x$-coordinate of the corresponding  pre-image point?

Comment: Start by listing the transformations in order that you would perform them, then undo them.

Comment: The fact that the variable is named $x$ is kind of confusing given that $x$ is also the name of its first coordinate. The meaning is clear from context, but still... it seems like an oversight by whoever devised the phrasing of this question.